# Positioning divs inside an image

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using **bootstrap** and I want to position 5 div's (5 horses) inside an image (track) which is placed inside a bootstrap panel.

This is the image:
[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

The track itself has to be a div with background image,something like this:

```
<div class="maintrack"></div>

.maintrack{
    background-image: url("../img/track/main.jpg");
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

There is a problem with current track at the moment, you can see it at http://infrox.us.lt/csgohorses/ , there is this huge gap below it..

Also, the 5 div's marked in green should have a horse image in their background.

Both horses and track must resize together with the window.

I hope I wrote it clearly and any help is strongly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have to show what you tried to program already, stackoverflow is meant to solve problems you pose, not your entire project from scratch..

Comment: That's because I'm stuck already, I'm sure the "height" parameter in css is wrong

Answer (score 1):

HTML images are not supposed to contain other elements.  You can use `position:absolute` for the div containers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!